# What is the etiquette of replying back emails and messages?

Tags: professionalism

On Saturday night, I found a company's HR persons LinkedIn request pending on my LinkedIn. I added her and instantly I got an email asking if I were interested in working for X company and they were looking for an immediate response.

I replied back asking what positions are open so I can respond back. I got a reply that they were looking for full stack web developers. I sent my resume to the mentioned email address but I feel very weird talking over at a Saturday night to a HR recruiter.

What is the etiquette of replying back to people on odd timings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **What are the etiquette of replying back to people on odd timings?**

I'm reminded of a humorous quote from the movie, [Swingers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117802/quotes):

> Trent: You know what. Ha ha ha Mike, laugh all you want but if you call too soon you might scare off a nice baby who's ready to party.
>   Mike: Well how long are you guys gonna wait to call your babies?
>   Trent, Sue: Six days.

One of the themes in this movie is about figuring out the perfect amount of time between when you get a phone number and when you call it.  The answer really is, though, that there's no perfect time, but sooner is probably better.

There has been no breach of etiquette by you or them. It was serendipity that you were both available to correspond this weekend.

There is absolutely no obligation on either of your parts to respond immediately or not respond.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the etiquette of replying back to people on odd timings?

With respect to time:

Since you replied to the person, there's nothing wrong about it. Are you concerned that the other person might think that you aren't interested or you are avoiding if you do not reply asap? Don't think of it that way. You may reply whenever you like. The email was sent during an 'odd time', so it wouldn't be bad if you do not reply asap. as Aaron mentioned in his answer:

> "There is absolutely no obligation on either of your parts to respond immediately or not respond." (+1)

Answer (score 1):

There is no etiquette - but the timeliness of your reply could be (over-) analyzed.

If you reply instantly on a Saturday evening, it could be viewed as you being quite diligent - or having no social life. If you wait until Monday, it could be viewed as you not having the appropriate sense of urgency or actually having a healthy work-life-balance.

The point is, you have absolutely no control over how the timing of your response will be viewed - so you may as well do what suits you and not attempt to guess what others might expect.